# Doctrine 2 don't generate entity class

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I wan't to generate entity class in Symfony 3.0.0 but when I type this command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

and I type this: "BundleName:EntityName", the process don't finish... Likewise I type this command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

No Error message appear... 
For information, when the Bundle is generated, There's no "entity" directory.

Have you a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have entities in an Entity folder in your BundleName bundle in src ?